# material-ui icon button highlights with an elliptical background when cursor is hovered over it

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

IconButton in `@material-ui/core/IconButton` is showing a weird elliptical background when I hover the cursor over it.

[image]

I thought it is a mistake by me, so I just copied the code from material-ui website, but the problem remains.

However, when I created new react project, and created an icon button in it, the background was the usual circle.

[image]

I'm new to react and can't figure out what is going on, I'm using icon button without any explicit styling,

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import WorkIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Work';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CssBaseline />
                <IconButton>
                    <WorkIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

`App.css`

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 80px;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}


.MuiCardContent-root-29 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.login {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from "./store/index";
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

`index.css`

```
body {
    background-color : #484848;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    color : #000000;
    text-align : center;
    font-family: "SIMPSON";
}
form {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}


button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100px;
}

.tableHeader {
    background-color: green !important;
}

.header {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.edit {
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.delete {
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**This problem persists in my whole project wherever I use icon buttons, and not just with this file only. And when I use this same file in a new project it works as expected: No elliptical backgrounds.**

**EDIT:**
The accepted answer works well. In my also case I tried setting the `width` in `button` of `index.css` to `auto` and it fixed the error too.

Comment: Right click->Inspect element, first guess would be the dimensions of the button aren't congruent.Hard to tell though with no example to reproduce it...

Comment: Please show the code/CSS of the elements around the `IconButton`. Something is affecting the width of the button. As Chris indicated, inspecting the element in browser Dev Tools is likely to show what CSS is affecting it.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I've updated the post, take a look

Comment: @ChrisW., , I've updated the post, take a look

Comment: @dev So remove code from your app until you find the simplest possible version of your app that still shows the problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I placed the simplest possible version of the code first, just the icon button. When community asked me to put the surrounding code

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I have updated the post to reproduce the problem with minimum possible info. Please take a look

Comment: Please show the contents of App.css and root.

Comment: Or remove the import of `root` if it reproduces without it. Go through the same process with App.css — remove as much of its contents as possible while still reproducing the problem. I suspect you will have answered your own question by the time you trim App.css down and see what in there causes this.

Comment: @dev I suspect the css that matters will involve `button` elements in some manner.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I have tried emptying the `App.css` but the problem remains. I have posted the conttents of `App.css`.

Comment: @dev Since you are exporting App, I assume you also have a separate index.js in play. Please show what is in it.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I've added code of `index.js` and `index.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `button` CSS in your index.css. It is setting the width of all buttons to 100px. `IconButton` is implemented via a button tag around the icon.

Fixing the look of `IconButton` is easy -- just remove that `button` CSS. The more tedious part is that presumably you want that button styling on all your other buttons.

One way to handle this is to change the following in `index.css`:

```
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100px;
}
```

to be a CSS class rather than targeting all buttons:

```
.standard-button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100px;
}
```

and then change places where you are rendering `button` elements to use:

```
<button className="standard-button">
```

instead of just `<button>`.

Comment: Thanks for describing the problem, but I'm newbie in react and css, so can you give the solution or at least guide me through.

Comment: I have set the `width` to `auto` and it works, can you please add it to your post so I can accept your answer

Answer (score 8):

This is what I did to remove the elliptical shape:

```
<IconButton style={{borderRadius: 0}}>
     <DeleteIcon/>
</IconButton>
```

Now, it will be a rectangular shape when hovered.

Comment: Nice! It worked for me too!

Comment: But, the ripple effect is still in circle shape, any ideas to make it rectangular as well?

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can override ripple root and child style to change border radius or background color.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    borderRadius: 0, // <---- icon button root style
    '.MuiTouchRipple-ripple .MuiTouchRipple-child': {  // <----this should change ripple style when clicked or touched
      borderRadius: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
  },
});
<IconButton className={classes.rippleRoot}>
  <WorkIcon />
</IconButton>
```

OR MUI5 with sx props

```
<IconButton
  sx={{
    borderRadius: 0,
    '.MuiTouchRipple-ripple .MuiTouchRipple-child': {
      borderRadius: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  }}
>
  <WorkIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: You are a life saver. This should be the accepted answer for truly making IconButtons square, ripple included.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the above two solutions didn't work for me. So I added `margin` and `width` to the parent element and `padding-right` to the child element in `App.css`.

```
//For the buttons on top

    button.MuiButtonBase-root {
      margin: 10px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    button.MuiButtonBase-root span span {
      padding-right: 50px;
    }
    
//For the checkboxes

    span.MuiButtonBase-root {
      margin-left: 10px;
      width: 45px;
    }
    
    span.MuiButtonBase-root span {
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use height and width with same value to have circular shade on hover-

```
<IconButton sx={{height:"40px",width:"40px"}}>
   <WorkIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
<IconButton style={{height:"45px",marginTop:"20px"}}>
    <DeleteIcon/>
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IconButton sx={{ borderRadius: 0 }}>
   <WorkIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: Please explain the code block.